# Plot a function which is dependent from an indefinite integral

Tags: plotting

I have a function which is:

```
Sqrt[3]/π Exp[y] Integrate[
 (p Cos[β y] + β q Sin[β y]) Sqrt[1 + β^2]/(p^2 + β^2 q^2), 
 {β, 0, ∞}
 ]
```

with

```
p = Sqrt[3*(1 + β^2)] Cosh[τ1 Sqrt[(1 + β^2)]] + 2 Sinh[τ1*Sqrt[(1 + β^2)]]
```

and

```
q = Sinh[τ1 Sqrt[(1 + β^2)]]
```

Is it possible to plot this function? 
I'm trying to put the expression of out[y] in Plot, but it seems that it does not work.

Comment: Tau1 is a number.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the code you are trying to use to `Plot` and the error you get. Include all the relevant variable values. All relevant information necessary to reproduce your problem should go **in the question not the comments**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
\[Tau]1 = 1;

p = Sqrt[3*(1 + \[Beta]^2)]*Cosh[\[Tau]1*Sqrt[(1 + \[Beta]^2)]] + 
   2*Sinh[\[Tau]1*Sqrt[(1 + \[Beta]^2)]];

q = Sinh[\[Tau]1*Sqrt[(1 + \[Beta]^2)]];

out[y_,N1_] := 
 Sqrt[3]/Pi*Exp[y]*
  NIntegrate[(p*Cos[\[Beta]*y] + \[Beta]*q*Sin[\[Beta]*y])*
    Sqrt[1 + \[Beta]^2]/(p^2 + \[Beta]^2*q^2), {\[Beta], 0, N1}]

Plot[out[y,10], {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that it works and it gives me the results that i want! Thank you! Could you explain me why it does not work with Infinity instead of N1? Just to not do the same error in the future.

Comment: P.s. may i ask you another question? I have a system of two partial differential equation to solve and i want to increase the density of point (the solutions have to be evaluated numerically): is this possible in the NDSolve function?

Comment: @Francesco_Lobosco It's very time consuming so I choose a finite upper limit.

Comment: @Francesco_Lobosco You can ask this new question in a new post.